# Find out missing range sequence

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0

I have range sequences. I want to find out is their any  missing sequence.

let’s say we have 3 margins 0 -25, 25-50, 75-100 
so program gives the result as  50 – 75. is missing sequence.

Comment: please include the code you have tried so far and tell us where you're stuck. Also, [How do I ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Please provide your code.

Answer (score 0):

As others have said you should provide at least some code for us to start off with. Also IMO this has nothing to do with ASP.NET.

The following is the solution which might be of help.

I have assumed a few things

- The margins which you are getting can be converted to `List<string>`
- There will be always be only 1 margin missing between any 2 margins. i.e. there will never be a case where your 3 margins are 0 -25, 25-50, 100-125 since here consecutive 2 margins are missing 50-75 and 75-100. **If this can be a case then please comment so that I can update my answer accordingly**
- The first margin in the list is always the start margin

Check out the below code

```
List<string> margin = new List<string>() { "0-25", "25-50", "100-125" };
List<List<int>> splitedMargin = new List<List<int>>();

foreach (var item in margin)
{
    var arr = item.Split('-');
    splitedMargin.Add(new List<int>() { int.Parse(arr[0]), int.Parse(arr[1]) });
}

//Required missing margin
List<string> missingMargin = new List<string>();
int marginSize = splitedMargin[0][1] - splitedMargin[0][0];

for (int i = 1; i < splitedMargin.Count; i++)
{
    if (splitedMargin[i - 1][1] != splitedMargin[i][0])
    {
        int missingMarginCount = (splitedMargin[i][0] - splitedMargin[i - 1][1]) / marginSize;

        if (missingMarginCount == 1)
            missingMargin.Add(splitedMargin[i - 1][1].ToString() + "-" + splitedMargin[i][0].ToString());
        else
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < missingMarginCount; j++)
            {
                missingMargin.Add((splitedMargin[i - 1][1] + (marginSize * j)).ToString() + "-" + (splitedMargin[i - 1][1] + (marginSize * (j + 1))).ToString());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: yes as you said, there can be more than one missing sequences.